# Tomcat with compression enabled causes error on OS X High Sierra

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, compression, zlib

We have been using Tomcat (v7) on OS X for quite some time now and never experienced any problems. However, after updating the OS to High Sierra, the web applications do not work anymore when compression is enabled in the server.xml.

Chrome constantly shows an ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED (obviously without any content displaying). When compression is switched off, everything works fine. I assume the root of the problem is Apple's upgrade of zlib in High Sierra. Everything was working fine on Sierra. The Tomcat log files look flawless -- there is no mention of any error occurring there.

Does anyone experience the same issue and managed to fix it or knows of a viable workaround *without disabling compression*?

Also, it would also be helpful if someone can confirm that newer versions of Tomcat do not experience this issue on High Sierra.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I could find no solution . Had to turn off compression in server.xml.Please post any solution you find

Comment: I had an additional problem where gzip stopped working on terminal. Replacing /sw/bin/gzip with homebrew installed gzip v1.8 (/usr/local/Cellar/gzip/1.8) solved that issue. For me - this compression problem of Tomcat is only limited to js and css files. Html is still getting rendered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in how the Java SDK `setLevel()` method is implemented. It is reported that compressed data resulting from setting the level is discarded by the SDK. That will result in corrupted compressed data. The fix for the bug can be found [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sherman/zlib1.2.11.fix/src/java.base/share/native/libzip/Deflater.c.sdiff.html), written by xuemingshen.

Comment: If the bug is in the JDK, why was it working in previous versions of OS X? I still think it is a zlib-related bug as Apple made a major upgrade there in High Sierra... In any case: What versions of the JDK are affected by the bug you talk about?

Comment: As far as I know, it affects all versions of the JDK until the fix is implemented. zlib changed its behavior within its specification, exposing the bug in the JDK. The JDK does not properly handle a return code from a zlib function, discarding data that that function could, and now in this application does, return. This is not a bug in zlib.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now and what you write makes sense. I really hope the JDK bug is fixed soon. Until then, I guess I have to switch off compression on my Tomcat servers.

Comment: This appears to be the underlying JDK bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184306

Comment: If you go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html and find on page for "zlib", you'll see that even the latest Oracle JDK 8 doesn't have a fix for this yet (as of 1.8u152).  I'd say stay tuned in that document to look for a release that does have it fixed.

Comment: Just thought I'd let you all know that since upgrading to JDK 9, the bug is no longer there. Mark was right when saying it was a JDK bug.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Workaround till an actual fix is found for this: turn off compression in your tomcat project's `server.xml` configuration.

Comment: Thanks, but if you read my question carefully, it says that I'm looking for a fix/workaround *without disabling compression*.

Answer (score 2):

Workarround/Hack for Windows: Unfortunately I am not familiar with OS X, but I am facing the same problem on Windows and have been able to find a little bit dirty  solution for it. The deflate.c error has been fixed in `8u162-ea`, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789

Unfortunately `8u162-ea` may not contain all fixes or is probably not good enough for a production environment.

To fix it under `8u152`, download and install the latest update from http://jdk.java.net/8/

Go to the installation folder (for instance `C:\Java\jdk8-162-ea\jre\bin\`) and copy the `zip.dll` which contains the fix (see [JDK 9 deflate.c fix](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/160ce50dd2e8)) and paste it on the same place under the `jdk 8u152`.

I hope you can find something similar under OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Fyi, OS X users, I tried installing JDK 8u162-ea from http://jdk.java.net/8/, and it did not fix the issue. I think the reason is that, unlike the Windows JDK, the OS X JDK does not bundle zlib, but rather uses the zlib that is included with OS X (/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib). This can be seen by looking at the shared libraries the java executable depends on:

```
$ otool -L /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 55179.0.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 45.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 744.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 945.11.0)
```

So I think we need a fix for this issue from Apple in the form of an 
 update for High Sierra.

Comment: No, the the JDK needs to be fixed. If the bug is fixed in the JDK, then it will work with the zlib in High Sierra.

Comment: Perhaps. However, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789 says the JDK bug was introduced in JDK 8u151, but I am experiencing the issue with JDK 8u144. And I started experiencing it after upgrading to High Sierra, not after upgrading my JDK.

Comment: As I understand it, the bug in the JDK has been there from the start. It is the new version of zlib that excites the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Our workaround for local dev: We use spring boot and have an EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer. After updated to High Sierra, same issue. The problem only exists for local development, so not something to push to production. As mentioned above we turned off compressing in our MainConfiguration as follows:

```
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer servletContainerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer) {
            ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) servletContainer).addConnectorCustomizers(
                    new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                        @Override
                        public void customize(Connector connector) {
                            AbstractHttp11Protocol httpProtocol = (AbstractHttp11Protocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
                            httpProtocol.setCompression("off");
                            httpProtocol.setCompressionMinSize(256);
                            String mimeTypes = httpProtocol.getCompressableMimeTypes();
                            mimeTypes += "," + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
                            mimeTypes += "," + "text/css";
                            mimeTypes += "," + "application/javascript";
                            httpProtocol.setCompressableMimeTypes(mimeTypes);
                        }
                    });
        };
    };
}
```